# HTML: sticky header jumps a little bit when scrolling

Tags: css, scroll, header

The problem is, that I'm trying to keep my header just stay at the top, when scrolling into other pages (inside) and when i'm selecting some of the other pages (with a lot of text) which makes scroll -> appear, the header jumps a little bit, which is annoying.

I tried text-align into a parent div and display: inline-block; into secondary. Tried to do the div relative and with left px etc but that makes it very unresponsive.

```
.header {
text-align: center;
}
.header h1 {
  display: inline-block;
  font-size: 77.2px;
  font-style: normal;
  font-weight: normal;
  letter-spacing: normal;
  line-height: 76px;
  text-transform: none;
  font-family: "Great Vibes", cursive;
}
.content {
  margin: 0 auto;
  width: 960px;
  top: 20px;
  z-index: 0;
  padding: 20px;
}
```

Comment: Please add more info about your pages. And usually, you need a `position: fixed` when you want a fixed element on the screens(only desktop, mobile doesn't support it).

Comment: index.php `<div class="header">
    <svg width="100" height="50" viewBox="0 0 500 200"></svg>
    <h1><font size="10">Welcome to my homepage!</h1>
  </div>`

Comment: Thing is i've tried position: fixed, but then the content isn't scrollable and you can't center it?

Answer (score 0):

The only way i actually can get it as i want is to set a wrapper with display: inline-block; and text-align: center with left: right 50 % and positio relative; looks as follows, problem is it doesnt really center and it's not responsive for bigger screens etc:

```
.header {
  display: inline-block;
}
.header h1 {
  text-align: center;
  left: 50%;
  right: 50%;
  position: relative;
  font-size: 77.2px;
  font-style: normal;
  font-weight: normal;
  letter-spacing: normal;
  line-height: 76px;
  text-transform: none;
  font-family: "Great Vibes", cursive;
}
```

Comment: HEADER only jumps on those pages exceeding the limit of text or photos, like: it needs to be scrolled to see more content. Why is this??

Answer (score 0):

It can be possible that there is an element (most commonly an image or video) that is wider than 100%. This causes somehow to screw things up a bit when having a fixed or sticky header. Try setting the max-width of the problematic element to 100%.